# Clown image in latex

Tags: graphics

What would be the latex symbol closest to the picture of a clown?  I searched through the site for "clown" but only found references to formatting an already existing picture of a clown.  For obvious reasons "detexify" does not help here, either.

Comment: I doubt that there is such a symbol in a regular font, but in some weird font being used with `Xelatex` or `LuaLaTeX` it could be possible, depending on the font, of course.

Comment: How about a simple smiley with a cone hat or something like that?

Comment: Unfortunately the closest person in tikzpeople is a jester

Comment: Most often it is gaming.SE that provides clickbait titles for HNQ, but it looks like prize is yours today.

Answer (score 25):

If you use `LuaLaTeX` or `XeLaTeX`, you can use the clown Unicode symbol (U+1f921) from a black&white emoji font:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\emojifont{Segoe UI Emoji}
\begin{document}
{\emojifont^^^^^^01f921}
\end{document}
```

[image]

`Segoe UI Emoji` is a Windows emoji font. On UNIX-like systems, the `Symbola` font is often installed or can be installed:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\emojifont{Symbola}
\begin{document}
{\emojifont^^^^^^01f921}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  Can you include a picture in your answer?  I see only tex code.  Which font should I use in a unix environment?  Lualatex does seem to be available on our system.

Comment: Is it correct that in the name of the font there are blanc spaces between Segoe and UI and between UI and Emoji?  Our unix system does not recognize the font.

Comment: The spaces are right, but the font is not installed on non-Windows systems. That is why I added the Symbola version. Sometimes Symbola isn't installed either, then you can install it yourself.

Answer (score 25):

By popular demand, clowns added from comments section.

EDIT to add color.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{stackengine,graphicx,scalerel,xcolor}
\setstackEOL{\\}
\setstackgap{S}{1pt}
\newcommand\Bullet{\textcolor{red}{$\bullet$}}
\newcommand\Wedge{\textcolor{blue}{$\wedge$}}
\begin{document}
Sad clown:
\scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\\\oo\\\Bullet\\\rotatebox{90}{)}}}{Xg}

Happy clown:
\scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\\\oo\\\Bullet\\\rotatebox{90}{(}}}{Xg}

Surprised clown:
\scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\\\oo\\\Bullet\\\rotatebox{90}{0}}}{Xg}

Too cool for school:
\scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\
  \scalebox{1.4}{$\bullet\makebox[0pt][c]{$-$}\bullet$}\\\Bullet\\---}}{Xg}

Sleeping clown:
\scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\\\-{}-\\\Bullet\\\rotatebox{90}{(}}}{Xg}

Clownthulhu: \scalerel*{\Shortstack{\Wedge\\\\\scriptsize oo\\\Bullet\\\scalebox{.16}[.75]{$\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup$}}}{Xg}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sleeping clown:`\scalerel*{\Shortstack{$\wedge$\\\\-{}-\\$\bullet$\\\rotatebox{90}{(}}}{Xg}`

Comment: @samcarter Clownthulhu:
`\scalerel*{\Shortstack{$\wedge$\\\\\scriptsize oo\\$\bullet$\\\scalebox{.16}[.75]{$\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup\mkern1mu\sqcup$}}}{Xg}`

Comment: Ohhh! Scary :) ~~~

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes can you add the code from the comments to your answer (including the picture) ?

Comment: @albert Done, per your request.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Many compliments to everybody. I upvote you execellent answer.

Answer (score 13):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \duck[magichat,bill=red]
\end{tikzpicture}   

\end{document}
```

[image]

With the [development version of the `tikzducks` package](https://github.com/samcarter/tikzducks) it is now possible to draw an harlequin duck:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{tikzducks}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\duck[harlequin,jacket=red,stripes={\stripes[color=blue, width=0.46, distance=3]}]
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You quack me up!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :)

Comment: ...but... that's a wizard, not a clown! ;-)

Comment: @Rmano artistic freedom :)

Comment: Happy to have occasioned some smiles at this site.

Comment: @Rmano ...and if you keep up talk like that, she'll turn you into a toad!

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The toad duck: https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQeIu.png

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes :-O So now I need a scared duck!